# RegEx: Match one of two patterns

Tags: regex

I have two regular expressions, one for validating a mobile number and one for a house phone number.

Mobile number pattern:

```
^((07|00447|\+447)\d{9}|(08|003538|\+3538)\d{8,9})$
```

Home number pattern:

```
((0|0044|\+44)\d{10}|(08)\d{9}|(90)\d{6}|(92)\d{6}|(437)\d{5}|(28)\d{6}|(37)\d{6}|(66)\d{6}|(82)\d{6}|(777)\d{5}|(93)\d{6})$
```

Is there a way to combine both of these expressions so that I can apply them to a 'Contact Number' field that would be valid if the input matched either expression?

Comment: Consider bookmarking the [Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496) for future reference.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Put both regexes into a non-capturing group separated by an alternation operator `|`.

```
^(?:((07|00447|\+447)\d{9}|(08|003538|\+3538)\d{8,9})|((0|0044|\+44)\d{10}|(08)\d{9}|(90)\d{6}|(92)\d{6}|(437)\d{5}|(28)\d{6}|(37)\d{6}|(66)\d{6}|(82)\d{6}|(777)\d{5}|(93)\d{6}))$
```

Comment: Why a non-capturing group here when a capturing group works as well and is more readable?

Answer (score 9):

Combine them with a pipe it's the or operator.

```
^((07|00447|\+447)\d{9}|(08|003538|\+3538)\d{8,9})|((0|0044|\+44)\d{10}|(08)\d{9}|(90)\d{6}|(92)\d{6}|(437)\d{5}|(28)\d{6}|(37)\d{6}|(66)\d{6}|(82)\d{6}|(777)\d{5}|(93)\d{6})$
```

Answer (score 5):

You can have to non-capturing groups with a `|` condition:

```
^(?:(07|00447|\+447)\d{9}|(08|003538|\+3538)\d{8,9})|(?:(0|0044|\+44)\d{10}|(08)\d{9}|(90)\d{6}|(92)\d{6}|(437)\d{5}|(28)\d{6}|(37)\d{6}|(66)\d{6}|(82)\d{6}|(777)\d{5}|(93)\d{6})$
```