# Regex - Match a single colon or a space followed by a hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex

I am writing some regex in Javascript.  Now I am trying to match a (single colon) or a (space followed by a hyphen).  I know if it was just a colon or a hyphen, I could do `[:-]`.  But I'm not sure how to match either (the colon) or (space followed by hyphen).

Trying to match
(a single colon)
or
(a space followed by a hyphen)

Comment: It's ambiguous what you mean - "(a single colon or a space) followed by a hyphen" vs. "(a single colon) or (a space followed by a hyphen)". Maybe see https://stackoverflow.com/q/27605991/3001761.

Comment: I added parentheses to help clarify what I meant.

Comment: Then yes see the link above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short and simple:

```
:    # Literal ':'
|    # or
\s-  # a whitespace followed by literal '-'.
```

Or, if you don't want line breaks and whatnot:

```
:| -
```

Comment: Does all that need to go into brackets?  Like this `[:|\s-]` ?

Comment: @dmikester No, it is fine as it is.

Comment: @dmikester1 Why would it go in brackets? Brackets are for defining character sets, not grouping. Grouping is done with parentheses.

Comment: @dmikester1 You obviously already know that, since you know about using `[:-]` to match either `:` or `-`.

Comment: @dmikester1 I'm afraid that linking to your tweet is not a suitable thing to do in a SO comment.

Comment: @InSync Can you show me where it says that?

Comment: @dmikester1 [When shouldn't I comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment), *secondary discussion*.